# Auto increment/ Identity possible to detect values itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, increment, identity

I have this table `ProcessList` where `TransactionID` value is supposed to be automatically incremented when a row is added in.

I can import data into this table from an Excel file. Is it possible to code it such that the value to start the increment from is automatically detected? Or at least such that no hard code is used because the Excel may contain any number of rows which I won't know.

I'm not sure if auto_increment or identity function in SQL is better for what I intend to do?

[image: ProcessList table]

Comment: Sql server itself will do it for you. If prev import ends with `TransactionID = 555`, next import will start assigning from `556`.

Comment: Hi, if my answer was helpful it would be very kind to vote it up and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to decide is, whether existing ID values within your EXCEL data may be thrown away or not.

If yes: Just exclude this column on insertion. The database will add a running ID by itself.

If no: You can insert ID-values using the statement

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ProcessList ON;
```

But you have to  be sure, that no existing ID value is re-inserted.

If you want to get the highest ID and do the insertion logic yourself you could use

```
SELECT MAX(TransactionID) + 1 FROM ProcessList
```

Answer (score 0):

With Identity(x,y) you can say where the incremention starts (y). Is that what you meant?